# addSubview doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm beginner in Objective-C. When I use addSubview in method setupView to see image, this doesn't work.

```
    h.


    @interface CollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController 

    @end

    @interface MyCell : UICollectionViewCell 

    @end
```

and

```
    m.


    @interface MyCell ()

    @end

    @implementation MyCell

    - (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
            self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) [self setupView];
            return self;

        }

    - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
    {
        self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
        if (self) [self setupView];
        return self;
    }

    -(UIImageView *)myImageView {

        UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView new];
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.jpg"];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true;
        return imageView;

    }

    -(void)setupView {

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        [self addSubview:self.myImageView];

    }

    @end
```

[image]

Comment: you need to give constraints or frame to the image. currently it is {0,0} size therefore cannot be seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of potential issues, but most likely the frame of the imageView isn't correct. Try creating it with

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.jpg"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

Comment: Thank you, now it's working) But why like this 

UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView new];
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.jpg"];

doesn't work?

Comment: Because `[UIImageView new]` creates an image view with a zero-sized frame. Setting the image doesn't change the frame size. Alternatively, you could have added `[imageView sizeToFit]` after setting the image and it would have worked too.

Comment: really, this variant woks too. Thanks for the explanation